# Get property value of object in an list

Tags: c#

I want to get an property value from an object that is in a list and put it into textbox.text

Below i have an example of my code:

The object:

```
public class Incident
    {
        public int Incident_id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Caller { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code in my form class:

```
List<Incident> incidentById = new List<Incident>();

 incidentById = db.GetIncidentById(ID);
```

when my list is filled i want to put the string Caller into an textbox somewhat like below:

```
textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById[1].Caller;
```

I'm stuck at this point so i hope someone can help me out.
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public List<Incident> GetIncidentById(int id)
        {

            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("IncidentLog")))
            {
                var output = connection.Query<Incident> ($"select * from Incidents where Incident_id like @id", new { id = "%id%" }).ToList();

                return output;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is this code not behaving in the way that you expect?

Comment: Why does `GetIncidentById` return a **List** of `Incident`s rather than one of them?

Comment: What do you think the difference between `incidentById[1].Caller` and `incidentById[0].Caller` is?

Comment: @Keveloper it gives an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. is it maybe because my list isnt filled properly?

Comment: @mjwills the first and the second object in the list? i know its probably not good to use an list while it holds only 1 object but i cant get my query to work without a list (dunno why....)

Comment: You will need to show us your implementation of `GetIncidentById`. Also try using `textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById.FirstOrDefault()?.Caller`;

Comment: I guess `GetIncidentById` returns a single incident, not a list. Of course this hasn't an indexer so this doesn't compile: `textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById[1].Caller`. Then you just need `textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById.Caller;`

Comment: @mjwills it compiles but it wont give any databack with you're code so my guess is there is no data in the list

Comment: Your query is wrong. `"%id%"` evaluates to **that literal string**. It is not inserting the `id` there. But let's take a step back - why are you `LIKE`ing an **integer**.

Comment: @mjwills because i took an example of the internet (and it compiled so i thought it was working )so probably its wrong in my implemetation?

Comment: Yes. It is wrong. `LIKE` should not be used with integer. What you want is `$"select * from Incidents where Incident_id = @id", new { id }`

Comment: @mjwills It worked!! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Then change `GetIncidentById` to return `Incident` rather than `List<Incident>`. And change `ToList` to `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't passing the right value into my query 
this did the trick!
 What you want is `$"select * from Incidents where Incident_id = @id", new { id }`

Comment: which means incidentById was not having any value and you were trying to access 2nd index of list.

Answer (score -2):

do you want first value should go?

check like.

```
if(incidentById.Count>0)
{
   textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById.First().Caller;
}
```

// or you can join all Caller in list like

```
if(incidentById.Count>0)
{
   textBoxCaller.Text = string.join(",",incidentById.Select(x=>x.Caller));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue that you are facing is that you are trying to access the second element in the list when there are not two or more elements in the list. If you are trying to access the first element in the list, then you could do either

```
textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById[0].Caller;
```

or

```
textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById.First().Caller;
```

If you do in fact want the second element of the list, then you should be checking to verify that it's length is at least two:

```
if(incidentById.Count >= 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, as mentioned in a comment, you should rename `GetIncidentById` to something that makes clear it is returning a list, like `GetIncidentsById` or something similar.

Comment: when i use textBoxCaller.Text = incidentById[0].Caller; i get :System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

Comment: This means that GetIncidentById is returning an empty list with no elements. Make sure that your list has elements before trying to access any of the elements.

Comment: Yes the list was empty. Thanks for the help